# Target pool with multiple load balancers?

Tags: amazon-web-services

As it's not possible to use one `target group` with multiple ELBs in AWS at the time this question is asked, Is it possible to assign the same `target pool` to multiple cloud load balancers in Google Cloud Platform?

**EDIT**

My app is a multi-tenant app, that should server thousands of domains, I came up with this solution using AWS ECS considering the limitations of:

- Certificates number per load balancer
- Target groups per ECS service.

[image]

So, I am thinking to serve the domain not only through one cluster, but multiple cluster sharing, as in the above diagram, its %50, %50 spreading of traffic on two clusters, in a method called active-active as I read at Shopify [blog](https://shopify.engineering/introduction-dns-traffic-management).

Answer (score 1):

**Answering your question - it is possible to have the same group of VM's assigned to multiple load balancers.**

Instead of using [target pool](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) you can create [Managed Instance Group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) (or [unmanaged](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances)) and select it as a target for your load balancer. From your question I deduced that we're talking about external load balancing. In a simple layer 4 TCP/UDP load balancer you can even add VM instances without the need to create groups or target pools.
[image]

And finally - you can use the same instances (or groups) as a backend for your load balancers (below I have two groups, but they can alsoo contain the same instances).
[image]

**----- U P D A T E -----**

You can also use multiple HTTPS load balancers (using SSL certificates) in front of your services. In your use case I believe the most correct one would be [Content-based load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#content-based_load_balancing):

> HTTP(S) Load Balancing supports content-based load balancing using URL maps to select a backend service based on the requested host name, request path, or both. For example, you can use a set of instance groups or NEGs to handle your video content and another set to handle everything else.

And yes - you can use multiple domains per one load balancer. The only limitation that I was able to find was a [maximum number of domains that can be assigned to one SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#ssl_certificates) which is 100.

This way you can have one cluster with a service (or many services) and dozens of domains assigned to it. Of course if you run out of resources (unlikely) then you can create another cluster but then you would have to configure it to be connected to the first one the way you want it.

**Additionally you can create multiple LB's for any instance group (I've tested up to 11 and stopped there)** though I can't find any documentation to give more insight if there's any limit (or rather what it is).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, so, Google Cloud is much more flexible that AWS as I did not see such options in AWS

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - if you provide more details description of your goal then I can provide more accurate answer.

Comment: Kindly check my EDIT, thank you.

Comment: Why exactly do you want two clusters instead of one ? (failver in different zone ?) Are the services be served under different path (domain.com/serv1 & domain.com/serv2) or different ports ?

Comment: Because one cluster can be used with maximum of 5 load balancers, however we continuously add more load balancers, its the same app deployed to all services. No different paths, but new domains.. think about it like Shopfiy, they have thousands of domains all using the same app..

Comment: I tested up to 11 LB's per instance group but stopped there - you may test it yourself and find out.